# Where should I manage the createdBy, modifiedBy, createDate, and modifiedDate?

Tags: asp.net

I want to insert the createdBy, modifiedBy, createDate, modifiedDate columns in every database table for manage user activity.

This is the first time I try to do this. Is there a best practice I could follow? Any design pattern good to manage this?

My first thought is to do this in my business logic layer, and in every business classes' insert and update method, i do something like this:

class.createDate = DateTime.Now;

or

class.modifiedDate= DateTime.Now;

class.modifiedBy = CurrentUser.Id;

or

class.createdBy = CurrentUser.Id;

Or there are much better way?

Bryan

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what types of business objects you are managing, and what the rules are around what the create/modified data is needed for. In most cases, this is a database audit trail, and there is no need for this information in the business logic layer. In that case, this information should live at the database level only. If you are using an ORM, that might mean you keep the data with your objects anyway. If you are using stored procs, then they all need to know how to take a user name to tag the record with. The datetimes can be handled by setting a default value of GetDate() on the column.

Comment: I am using ORM. Since UserName or UserId can be obtain easily from asp.net code, so thats why I was thinking do all the works at asp.net code instant of database store procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing to consider is what time do you want stamped?  Do you want the time of the application server or the time on the database server?  I always go for the DB server.  So in that case the stored procedure (or SQL statements) should be getting current time.

-Krip

Comment: how about the username or userId who made the action?

Comment: Yes that needs to come through from the business layer.  However, I use defaults at the database level for that in case someone manipulates the data directly using database management tools.  This way usernames get stamped even if business layer / application is bypassed.

Comment: I haven't consider someone would done something directly from database. It is a good point.

Answer (score 0):

You should manage `CreatedDate` and `ModfiedDate` at database label only. Default value of the CreatedDate should be `Getdate()/SYSDATE` and you don’t need to set this value.  For ModifiedDate again set the `GETDATE()/SYSDATE` on every update.

You only need to pass the ModifiedBy userid from your application to the database, in case of insert set the userid for both the column and in the case of update only update the Modified by userId column.

Comment: so you means do the time at trigger and do the userid at the asp.net code?

Comment: Time of insertion/updation at database level (Not trigger), and you need to pass the logged in userid from your ASP.NET code.

Answer (score 0):

For createdBy and modifiedBy, I usually set this in my business layer using the username of the current user. For createDate and modifiedDate I do this in the 'after' triggers in the database.

Comment: you got what I am concerning. Since UserName or UserId can be obtain easily from asp.net code, so thats why I was thinking do all the works at asp.net code instant of database store procedure.

Comment: What if someone manipulates data via database tools outside the application?  So some database defaults that stamp username would be useful.  For example, SQL Server has SUSER_SNAME() for this purpose.  Then you can still pass in application username to override the default.

Comment: I haven't consider someone would done something directly from database. It is a good point.

Comment: @Krip: The question is specific to Asp.net. My suggestion is to use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name to get the username of the currently logged on user in the application and an 'after' trigger to get the time in the db server. This being because the app could be in a server farm situation and time in different web servers may not be in sync. The suser_sname outside the Asp.Net app will not necessarily map to any Asp.Net app user, making the use of suser_sname unreliable in this situation.

Comment: I fully agree that the username should come from ASP.NET and get stamped on the records so that we know what application user did the work.  I am also addressing the situation where someone updates the database directly.  In our systems we catch username from both angles.  In fact our triggers on UPDATE look to see if the UpdateUsername was set and IF NOT, then set to database user.